# I need to run/suspend the virtual machine using VMware API as if I had used Web Browser(Chrome, IE, etc)

Tags: api, vmware

ClientI have the question about VMware API.

How i can execute powerOn/Suspend virtual machine with use VMware API through VMware Web Client?

Usually, with use VMware API I start virtual machine bypassing the VMware Web Client directly on vCenter, but I want send command "PowerOnVM_Task" through VMware Web Client and then already to on vСenter.

I need to run/suspend the machine using vmware API as if I had used Web Browser(Chrome, IE, etc).

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Java.

First go through Steve Jin's [VI-Java API](http://vijava.sourceforge.net/) . Then learn about the [Managed Object Reference](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk25pubs/ReferenceGuide/vmodl.ManagedObjectReference.html) . After that you can start coding...

Now look this is how I have done but this required many other helper classes and methods. So you have to pull out the crux out of it. And try to understand how I am starting the VM. You can go through the documentation of Steve Jin's vi-java api where you can find some examples which might help you.

```
powerOnVM(ManagedObjectReference vmMOR){
try{
//Get the name of VM
String vmName= (String)client.getServiceUtil().getDynamicProperty(vmMOR, "name");

// You may need to perform other works like NIC config or relocating VM at exact host etc.

//Try to start thge VM
ManagedObjectReference taskMOR = client.getServiceInstance().powerOnVM_Task(vmMOR, null);
Thread hook = client.addShutdownHook(taskMOR);
client.startCancelThread(getRequestNo(), taskMOR);

// Wait for the task to complete.
client.getServiceUtil().waitForTask(taskMOR);
client.removeShutdownHook(hook);

// Get the task state
TaskInfo tinfo = (TaskInfo)client.getServiceUtil().getDynamicProperty(taskMOR, "info");
if (TaskInfoState.success.equals(tinfo.getState())) { // success
    logDecoratedMsg("Virtual Machine " + vmName + " powered on successfully"); 
} else {
       throw new Exception(tinfo.getError().getLocalizedMessage(), tinfo.getError().getFault());
  }
}
catch(InvalidPowerState e){throw new Exception("Virtual Machine is in an invalid power state"}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to issue powerOn/Suspend tasks programatically through the vSphere Web Client. I don't think this is possible as the web client doesn't expose an API. You'll have to connect to the vCenter (web services) directly. The web client is just a UI. Why don't you want to connect to yout vCenter directly?

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. I changed "VMware Web Server -> VMware Web Client" for more understanding.
I don't want connect to my vCenter directly because i want send messages(packets) is the same as sends web browser to VMware Web Client.

Comment: There are two parts of the web client. A client-side application that runs in your browser (mostly flash) and the web client server. When you trigger a power-on or a suspend through the web client UI, to the best of my knowledge the web client server will use the documented vCenter API to trigger said power-on or suspend. The communication between web client and web client server is not documented, so don't use this way. Use the official, documented and stable SOAP-based vCenter API.